# How To Load File Automatically into File Up loader with browse

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have requirement , I have asp page with file uploader and button name `"upload"`...
Without using the browse ,i want to load some default files in file uploader ,suppose that I have folder in `c:\serverfloder` and i have image `"image1.jpg"` in that ..when user  request 1 time ,i want to `automatically load the file into file uploader`  .. 
Based on user requirement we give chance the change the file  file ....i don't want to restrict the user.

Comment: You cannot do that for security reasons. Imagine if you could specify any file on the users hard drive for upload. That would make it easy to upload personal files without the user knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following code , which I wrote for my application

```
 string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
        string FileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
        string FileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString();
        string FileContent = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString();
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        br.Close();
        fs.Close();
        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO [testdb1].[dbo].[tblAttachment]([f_name],[fileSize],[attachment],[contentType]) VALUES(@f_name,@fileSize,@attachment,@contentType)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@f_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fileSize", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(FileSize);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@attachment", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@contentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FileContent;
```

and also visit here for [File Opeartions in C#](http://niharstechnicalfunda.blogspot.in/2013/03/file-operations-in-c-net.html#!/2013/03/file-operations-in-c-net.html)  and their will be other method which store your image directly to specific folder or try this..will directly save your file to folder

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)

  {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"D:\MVC Application Demos\FileOpearationsDemo\FileOpearationsDemo\Files\" + FileUpload1.FileName);

        }
```